# Tool for automatic Windows file sync, no GUI?

Tags: windows

I'm writing a script on Windows 8 that will set up automatic file syncing between two folders. I am looking for a syncing utility that has the following properties (roughly in order of importance):

- can be called from a batch script, has reasonable documentation (doesn't HAVE to be a batch script, the script could be in Python or something, but it cannot use any proprietary software)
- automatic updating (as soon as an item is changed in the source folder it updates in the destination folder)
- free
- incremental updates (does not copy all the files every time)

I've researched a bunch of options, but I mostly seem to find utilities with GUIs or that cannot update automatically. Any thoughts?

**Edit**
Thanks guys. It looks like there isn't anything that does exactly all these things, but I thought it was worth a shot to avoid reinventing the wheel. I'll look into rsync combined with some sort of folder monitoring utility to get the auto-updating to work.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync

Comment: Or [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/).

Comment: That's not true.  Did you look at robocopy /mon and /mot?  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx  If you give exact folder names I could give you example command.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Robocopy. I believe it still comes bundled with Windows 8 and can be configured to do what you need.

Comment: I was under the impression Robocopy is just a copy utility and doesn't do much syncing functionality. I don't think it can automatically update when the source folder changes. I also think it doesn't do incremental updates.

Comment: It is but with some batch scripting can be made to act as a file sync tool. I don't know if you'll be able to find a piece of software that does *exactly* what you need, though look into Rsync as suggested by the other users.

Comment: Robocopy options allow copying only new/changed files (no delta within files), and there is an option to continuously poll for changes, with configurable poll interval (seconds or hours depending on your expected rate of change).  See http://serverfault.com/a/200470/33647

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528298/rsync-for-windows. On any unix type system rsync works like a charm

Comment: Which answer did you mean? That link goes to the question...

Comment: any which links to some program that can use :) it's almost the same question

Answer (score 0):

You can create a scheduled task from the command line: http://www.howtogeek.com/51236/how-to-create-modify-and-delete-scheduled-tasks-from-the-command-line/

```
SchTasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN “My Task” /TR “C:RunMe.bat” /ST 09:00
```

And use the appropriate strings in Robocopy (included in most current versions of windows) to tell it to sync the folders: http://improve.dk/simple-file-synchronization-using-robocopy/

```
robocopy \\SourceServer\Share \\DestinationServer\Share /MIR /FFT /Z /XA:H /W:5
```

You could possibly replace the "C:RunMe.bat" line in the SchTasks command with your desired robocopy arguments to fit the whole thing into a single batch file. Though, for management sake, I'd keep them as two separate files just kept together.